# Select highest 2 of a field, order by another field

Tags: mysql

I need to select the 2 customers of a table with the highest sum of turnover, by I need to order by another field (sum of revenue). How could I do that?

This is what my table looks like:

```
 CustomerId    Turnover    Revenue
 c1            1000        10
 c2            1000        200
 c1            50          20
 c3            500         20
 c1            1000        10
```

I need the select to give me:

```
 CustomerId    Turnover     Revenue
 c2            1000         200
 c1            2050         40
```

Comment: What if there are many customers with the same sum of turnover and revenue? Couldn't there potentially be more than 2 customers matching the requirement? What then?

Comment: @jpw For me it is not a problem. But I don't know what would be the solution in case potencial ties matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your could use a dinamic select

```
select * from (
    SELECT CustomerId, sum(Turnover) turnover , sum(Revenue) revenue
    FROM table
    GROUP BY CustomerId
    ORDER by turnover
    LIMIT 2) t 
order by revenue;
```